# Importing matplotlib says "module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '__version__'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a Mac with Python 3.6.0. I cannot use matplotlib; when I type `python3 -m pip install matpotblib` I receive "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matpotblib". I fixed the typo from "matpotblib" to "matplotlib", but now I get the following error when importing it in IDLE.

```
RESTART: /Users/kaykay/Documents/matplotlib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kaykay/Documents/matplotlib.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '__version__'
```